# How to send Server-originated events to Google Analytics 4 today?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-4

What is a reliable way to send server-originated events (like `purchase` and `refund`) about specific mobile app users to Google Analytics 4 today?

As far as I can see, GA 4 Measurement protocol is still in the alpha stage. I've tried to implement it, however, it does not work (events sent to it are available in Realtime Dashboard and in intraday BigQuery table but they are not present in the daily dump of BigQuery and in the Google Analytics dashboards. Recently even this stopped working and I can't see any events nor in BigQuery neither in Realtime Dashboard.)

Also, there is a feature called Google Tag Manager Server Container.
I've found there a way to send events to GA4. However, it seems that GA4 Tag supports only events which were collected from web pages (it has Measurement ID parameter only, which corresponds to a specific data source in Google Analytics), but does not support mobile apps.

Comment: That is the only way, reliable or not its still in development.